# spark handling of time zone for builtin date & time related functions

Tags: apache-spark, time, apache-spark-sql

Assuming I have a timestamp like one obtained from `current_timestamp()` UDF inside spark when using a function like: `hour()`, `minute()`, ... . How can I specify a time zone?

I believe that https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18350 introduced the support for it. But can't get it to work. Similar to the last comment on the page:

> ```
> session.read.schema(mySchema)
>             .json(path)
>             .withColumn("year", year($"_time"))
>             .withColumn("month", month($"_time"))
>             .withColumn("day", dayofmonth($"_time"))
>             .withColumn("hour", hour($"_time", $"_tz"))
> ```
>
> Having a look at the definition of the hour function, it uses an Hour
>   expression which can be constructed with an optional timeZoneId. I
>   have been trying to create an Hour expression but this is
>   Spark-internal construct - and the API forbids to use it directly. I
>   guess providing a function hour(t: Column, tz: Column) along with the
>   existing hour(t: Column) would not be a satisfying design.

I am stuck on trying to pass a specific time zone to the default builtin time UDFs.

Comment: Did you try changing the configuration property `spark.sql.session.timeZone` ?

Comment: Not yet. I thought this could be passed directly to the functions. You suggestion looks like a fix - but is it also possible to specify the timeZone at the function level?